# Removing spaces between strings

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
str_=raw_input('Enter:')
for i,k in enumerate(str_):
    if str_[i] != str_[i].upper():
        v=str(str_[i].upper())
        print v,  
    else:
        c= str(str_[i].lower())
        print c,
```

This code helps swapping the cases My output is right but i'm getting spaces in between i tried all possible ways to remove the spaces like re.sub,strip(\n),remove(' ','' ) still my output is like this

```
  >>>Enter:juNgLe
  J U n G l E
```

where i want my output:`JUnGlE`

Comment: use sys.stdout.write(c) instead of print. See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/493386/how-to-print-in-python-without-newline-or-space

Comment: @ZeenaZeek Ohh thank you so much it worked :)

Answer (score 1):

You can easily import the print function from python3 which is better than python 2x's print statment

```
from __future__ import print_function

str_=raw_input('Enter:')
for i,k in enumerate(str_):
    if str_[i] != str_[i].upper():
        v=str(str_[i].upper())
        print(v, end='')
    else:
        c= str(str_[i].lower())
        print(c, end='')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
str_=raw_input('Enter:')

response="";

for i,k in enumerate(str_):
    if str_[i] != str_[i].upper():
        v=str(str_[i].upper())
        response=response+v
    else:
        c= str(str_[i].lower())
        response=response+c
print response
```

try to add all the letters to new string variable and then print that new variable

Answer (score 1):

For this solution you'll need to use print from `Python 3`. This should work:

```
from __future__ import print_function

str_=raw_input('Enter:')
for i,k in enumerate(str_):
    if str_[i] != str_[i].upper():
        v=str(str_[i].upper())
        print(v, end="")
    else:
        c= str(str_[i].lower())
        print(c, end="")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `sys.stdout.write(c)` instead of `print`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493386/how-to-print-in-python-without-newline-or-space)

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the function [`swapcase()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#str.swapcase) to accomplish what you want:

```
name = "ss A"
print name.swapcase().replace(" ","")
>>> "SSa"
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't loop over the string.

```
str_=raw_input('Enter:')
str_.replace(" ","").swapcase()
```

the `.swapcase()` *method* is not deprecated and exactly what you need.